# From Data mining to RDF

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology

I have been going through Apache Jena tutorials and they are pretty straightforward. My question is, if I am doing data mining on text ex: For each paragraph in a text book I am getting people's names, places, keyphrases etc... What is the easiest way to transform these to rdf using an ontology?

Comment: ha, if only somebody knew how to transform raw text to semantic data reliably! Basically, you need humans, or an AI that's just as smart. I'm afraid, your question is not very specific... doesn't seem like a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: RDF is triples, thus, you have to extract triples from text. this is ongoing research and will never be solved for a general case with 100% precision + recall for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your entities extracted from text as strings (e.g. <person name>, <organization name>, <keyword1...2>, etc.), you can just use the `ModelFactory` in Jena to create a model and then fill it with resources using `model.createResource(uri)`, and properties on the resource using `.addProperty()` as can be found in the Jena examples and documentation. Those samples show also how to print the model out in RDF ( iterating through statements and using `stmt.getSubject()`, `stmt.getPredicate()`, and  `stmt.getObject()`. As far as the ontology goes, you can either invent your own or more preferably, use existing vocabulary. Suppose, for example, you decide to use the Person class from schema.org. Then you'd need to specify the `rdf:type` of your resource to be `https://schema.org/Person`. Likewise, you could use properties from that vocabulary such as `https://schema.org/name` which inherits from `https://schema.org/Thing` (as all can be found in [schema.org docs](https://schema.org/docs/schemas.html)). You do not necessarily need your ontology to be in your model or database so long as you are structuring your instances properly with URIs identifying classes and properties from the vocabularies or ontologies you use. If you do have the programmatic need, you can have the vocabulary in your model, but then I think you should look at [Jena docs on Ontology](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/)).